# determine the URL in the browser address bar (NOT the real address)

Tags: javascript, php

I have two urls - biothoughtblog.co and playfight.co. The first is forwarding to the second and masking is used. I am using this

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>

<?php
  echo curPageURL();
?>
```

on the page http://www.biothoughtblog.co/test.php - however, it echoes the real URL which is http://www.playfight.co/test.php. I need it to echo the URL that is in the address bar. I know very very little Javascript - is it what I need to be using here?

Thanks a lot.

P.S Oh, and the purpose is to run the same website under two different domains and different branding (logo, etc).

Comment: read about url rewrite

Comment: If you want to run the site under two different domains, don't use domain masking. Point them both at real servers. You could use different virtual name hosts on the same machine and set shared DocumentRoots and different configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because http://www.biothoughtblog.co/test.php is **framing** http://www.playfight.co/test.php.

```
<frame src="http://www.playfight.co/test.php" frameborder="0" />
```

PHP has no way of knowing that it is loaded inside a frameset, and how to get the URL of the parent frame.

You want to avoid using the "masking" feature of your registrar or DNS provider. Point the biothoughtblog.co domain to the same hosting server, ensure that your hosting account is setup for both domains. Then biothoughtblog.co wil be hitting your website directly, and PHP will know what it is.

Comment: Does the referrer not contain the URL of the outer frame?  Sure, this would only work if you knew your stuff was being loaded in a frame, but that might work depending on the use.

Comment: @Brad It might. Possibly worth a shot if you have no other choice. Referrer header isn't reliable though, and I think the OP doesn't understand what masking is doing to the domain. Just a bad idea all around.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the search engine positioning complications (duplicate content penalties). Biothought name will be only used in very special narrow circumstances and I don't want people to bookmark it, link to it or use it at all as a real site.

Comment: @Natalia If you frame it, PHP doesn't have a [guaranteed] way to get the parent frame address. There's no good way to get what you want with domain masking enabled.

Comment: @Brad - how would I get URL of the outer frame?

Comment: Try echoing $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]. Just realize there are many cases where web browser won't send the referer header (proxies often strip it, etc)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. This is for a joint venture where one of the partners uses numerology and refuses to access the website by playfight.co and needs to use his own name. Basically, this is for one person access - we do need him on the project though, and have to do whatever it takes to keep him happy. :)

Comment: Sounds like you need a new partner?  :-D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything in PHP to run the same website under two different domains.

If you are using apache, open your conf file, locate your virtual host config and add a serverAlias.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName biothoughtblog.co
    ServerAlias playfight.co
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: We need to change the branding and some graphics depending on the URL though.